# ERROR Error: No provider for Router! at injectionError (core.es5.js:1231) [angular]

Tags: angular

I am getting this error. My angularJS 2 application is small one now. I am new to AngularJS. Please, help! Thanks you in advance.
app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
```

dashboard.module.ts

```
import { ToolbarMultirow } from './toolbar-multirow';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { DashboardService } from './dashboard/shared/dashboard.service';
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    DashboardModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ToolbarMultirow,
    // DashboardComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    DashboardService
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    ToolbarMultirow,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { DashboardService } from './shared/dashboard.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  exports: [
      DashboardComponent,
      CommonModule,
      FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    // DashboardService
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    // DashboardComponent
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

> DashboardComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view:
>   Object, nodeIndex: 1, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object}
>   View_DashboardComponent_Host_0 @ DashboardComponent_Host.html:1
>   proxyClass @ compiler.es5.js:13572 DebugContext_.logError @
>   core.es5.js:12953 ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.es5.js:1149
>   (anonymous) @ core.es5.js:4660 ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:365
>   onInvoke @ core.es5.js:4125 ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:364 Zone.run
>   @ zone.js:125 (anonymous) @ zone.js:760 ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:398 onInvokeTask @ core.es5.js:4116 ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:397 Zone.runTask @ zone.js:165 drainMicroTaskQueue @
>   zone.js:593 zone.js:569 Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for
>   Router! ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No
>   provider for Router!
>       at injectionError (core.es5.js:1231) [angular]
>       at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1269) [angular]
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2770) [angular]
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2809) [angular]
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKey (core.es5.js:2741) [angular]
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.get (core.es5.js:2610) [angular]
>       at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (core.es5.js:3557) [angular]
>       at resolveDep (core.es5.js:10930) [angular]
>       at createClass (core.es5.js:10799) [angular]
>       at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10627) [angular]
>       at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:11977) [angular]
>       at createRootView (core.es5.js:11882) [angular]
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13013) [angular]
>       at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12474) [angular] Error
>       at injectionError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:2025:86) [angular]
>       at noProviderError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:2063:12) [angular]
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:3564:19) [angular]
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:3603:25) [angular]
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKey (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:3535:25) [angular]
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:3404:21) [angular]
>       at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:4351:52) [angular]
>       at resolveDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:11724:45) [angular]
>       at createClass (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:11593:32) [angular]
>       at createDirectiveInstance (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:11421:37) [angular]
>       at createViewNodes (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:12771:49) [angular]
>       at createRootView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:12676:5) [angular]
>       at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:13807:42) [angular]
>       at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:13268:12) [angular]
>   consoleError @ zone.js:569 handleUnhandledRejection @ zone.js:574
>   _loop_1 @ zone.js:609 drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:613 zone.js:571 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Router! Error
>       at injectionError (core.es5.js:1231) [angular]
>       at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1269) [angular]
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2770) [angular]
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2809) [angular]
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKey (core.es5.js:2741) [angular]
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.get (core.es5.js:2610) [angular]
>       at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (core.es5.js:3557) [angular]
>       at resolveDep (core.es5.js:10930) [angular]
>       at createClass (core.es5.js:10799) [angular]
>       at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10627) [angular]
>       at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:11977) [angular]
>       at createRootView (core.es5.js:11882) [angular]
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13013) [angular]
>       at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12474) [angular]
>       at injectionError (core.es5.js:1231) [angular]
>       at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1269) [angular]
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2770) [angular]
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2809) [angular]
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKey (core.es5.js:2741) [angular]
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.get (core.es5.js:2610) [angular]
>       at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (core.es5.js:3557) [angular]
>       at resolveDep (core.es5.js:10930) [angular]
>       at createClass (core.es5.js:10799) [angular]
>       at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10627) [angular]
>       at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:11977) [angular]
>       at createRootView (core.es5.js:11882) [angular]
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13013) [angular]
>       at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12474) [angular]
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:712) []
>       at :4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3326:17 []
>       at :4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3342:33 []
>       at Zone.run (zone.js:125) [ => ]
>       at :4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3448:57 []
>       at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165) [ => ]
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:593) [] consoleError @ zone.js:571 handleUnhandledRejection @ zone.js:574
>   _loop_1 @ zone.js:609 drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:613

Comment: I solved it by removing dependencies such as Rooter, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the RouterModule to the imports.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { DashboardService } from './shared/dashboard.service';

@NgModule({
imports: [
  RouterModule, <-------
  CommonModule,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  HttpModule
],
declarations: [
  DashboardComponent
],
exports: [
  DashboardComponent,
  CommonModule,
  FormsModule
],
providers: [
  // DashboardService
],
bootstrap: [
  // DashboardComponent
]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

Comment: how do you know which module has to be imported. I am also getting same problem, so its necessary for me to know exactly which module has to be imported